# Any cloud tool to work on a Flutter Project?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a Flutter freelancer, my laptop isn't available to me all time, isn't there a cloud-based service that I purchase or subscribe so I can host a Flutter project online, develop and run the emulator over there rather than running it locally?

Answer (score 1):

*1) You can use version control tool git and push your code to github. You can clone these project to any of your laptop which you are using.*

*2) Then, you can use CI/CD tools like codemagic or CircleCI to to make new builds every time whenevery you make a new push to the git hub ripo.*

*3) You can use firebase test lab to test your builds, firebase will send you test result (screenshots and screen video )to your mail or you can check that on firebase console.*

*4) You can also use firebase app distribution to get or track your all build so that you can test that build on any of your phone all you have to do is just download firebase app distribution and sign with your mail*

**requirements**

> You must pay some money to CI/CD tools. But you also get free trial

> You must register you app on firebase

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know as of now there is no such service available at the moment that can support this but you can check **FlutterFlow** which is an online tool for designing flutter apps with Firebase. You can also download the source code from there.

Here is the link for the same:
https://flutterflow.io/#